# Knex for posgres using default schema to create lock table which is conflicting for multiple projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, migration, database-migration, knex.js

I am using knex with postgres in my Node project, I have two different project using same database but different schemas. I can operate with different schemas while writing any query or doing migration using
***knex.schema.withSchema*** , but knex is not creating lock table in those respective schemas. It uses default public schema in database to create lock tables. So first project would migrate fine but when I migrate second project it throws error- **Error: The migration directory is corrupt, the following files are missing: 20210430124918_test.ts**

which is the file for first project. Since it uses same public schema with same name for creating lock table it thinks file is missing.

I don't want to change the migration-lock file name in knexfile.ts, Is there a way to specify which schema to be used for creating lock tables for different projects.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I normally change the table name using --migrations-table-name (or in code). Not sure right now, but I think this impacts the lock table, too. Other than that, try setting the searchPath in the knexfile, or if that is not practical - you can always do ALTER ROLE app1 SET search_path = "app1"; -- provided that your apps use separate DB users.

Answer (score 0):

For different projects you need to specify a separate knexfiles which tells the correct migration directory and correct schema name for migrations to use.

https://knexjs.org/#Migrations-API

Though would be a lot easier to just use completely separate databases for both projejcts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if you want to handle it by code itself the  update code somewhat like

```
const migrationConfig = {
      directory: this.migrationDirectory,
      tableName: 'knex_migration_reporter', //check here I changed the name
    };
 
    let q = await this.dbClient.client().migrate.latest(migrationConfig);
```

If you check the type file you can see the interface it accepts

```
  interface MigratorConfig {
    database?: string;
    directory?: string | readonly string[];
    extension?: string;
    stub?: string;
    tableName?: string;
    schemaName?: string;
    disableTransactions?: boolean;
    disableMigrationsListValidation?: boolean;
    sortDirsSeparately?: boolean;
    loadExtensions?: readonly string[];
    migrationSource?: MigrationSource<unknown>;
    name?: string;
  }
```

So you can provide different schema names or different knex table in the same schema whatever you like.